# how to find the value and index of max/min value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array and I want to get the max value and its index. I'm using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    //max-element
using namespace std;
#define J 5

int main(int argc, char** argv)
...
double ucolumn[J]={};

for(j=0;j<J;j++)
    for(i=0;i<I;i++)
        ucolumn[j]+=u[i][j];

double q=*max_element(ucolumn[0],ucolumn[J]) << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

but it gives me an error of "illegal indirection", "mismatch in formal parameter list"

Comment: you might want to change `#define J 5` to `static const unsigned int J = 5;` which provides type checking.

Comment: in order to get the index or the value. Because now I just need the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the algoritm with iterator rather than valies:

```
std::max_element(ucolumn, ucolumn + J)
```

Comment: I've tried this one too. It doesn't work either. I still have this error "mismatch in formal parameter list"

Comment: @Anna you also have to remove the `<< endl;`

Comment: @Anna: Use `double *q = max_element(ucolumn, ucolumn+J);` and then use arithmetic `q - ucolumn`.

Comment: @Jesse, thanks it works but isn't it risky to rely on the memory location? I have to solve the problem in thousand times of iterations. Are the values of ucolumn and q going to be their initial memory location?

Comment: @Anna: Sorry, what do you mean by "going to be their initial memory location"? As 1d arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous memory, arithmetic on them is valid.

Comment: @Anna: If you are worried about using pointer arithmetic or want a method that is portable to other C++ containers, you can use `std::distance` to compute the difference between two pointers/iterators.

Comment: @Jesse: Can I extend this idea to a matrix too? I want to find the position of min value in each row of a matrix.

Comment: @Anna: A matrix is just a sequence of arrays. All you need for `std::min_element()` to work is an iterator (and pointers qualify as iterators). More precisely, you'd need a _forward iterator_, i.e. one which can traverse a sequence multiple times. To find the position of the min value of each row you'd just apply `std::min_element()` once for each row and store the result somewhere.

Comment: @Diemtr Kuhl: I thought the same but it didn't work! I posted my code as a question, if you can please take a look at my code,thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449934/how-to-find-the-index-of-min-value-in-each-row-of-a-matrix-in-c